# My Bubble Sort Program worked for one case but not for other. How this is Possible?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter size of array-";
    cin>>n;
    int arr[n];
    cout<<"Enter all elements"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    cout<<"Your Entered elements are"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<",";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    for(int x=0;0<n-x;x++){
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(arr[i]>arr[i+1]){
                int tem=arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[i+1];
                arr[i+1]=tem;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"Sorted Array"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<",";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> For first case
> Enter size of array-6
> Enter all elements
> 4 5 3 2 1 9
> Your Entered elements are
> 4,5,3,2,1,9,
> Sorted Array
> 1,2,3,4,5,9,
> For second case(This have Problem)
> Enter size of array-4
> Enter all elements
> 20
> 40
> 30
> 50
> Your Entered elements are
> 20,40,30,50,

Comment: Your program has undefined behaviour due to accessing `arr[n]` on the last iteration of the inner loop. In any case `int arr[n];` is VLA, [which isn't part of C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097) and a ticking time bomb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access `arr[i+1]`. When `i = n-1`, `arr[i+1] = arr[n]`, so your access is out-of-bounds.

Also, `int arr[n]` isn't valid C++. You should use `std::vector<int>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bubble sort,you should
<code>
 for (var i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < len - 1 - i; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) {      
                var temp = arr[j+1];       
                arr[j+1] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
</code>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my Que. but I want to ask what wrong in My code.